How does Newton's third law apply to forces between fluids and solid surface?
What is the direction of the force exerted by the fluid on the solid surface and what is the direction of the force exerted by the solid surface on the fluid?
If I am not wrong, I think the force exerted by the fluid on the solid surface is the pressure. And the force that the solid surface exerts on the fluid is the weight.
But I am not sure, when considering a fluid in a flask. Does the flask exert a force on the fluid? And what about the buoyant force and viscosity?
Can someone explain this?

It is stress in both cases.  For an ideal fluid (zero viscosity), the stress is perpendicular to the solid surface and the normal stress exerted by the solid surface is also equal to the fluid pressure.

Obviously, the flask has to exert a force. The liquid in the flask  exerts pressure on the flask and if the flask doesn't apply any force, it would violate Newton's third law. The flask exerts a force called stress on the liquid.
The force exerted by the solid is not weight always necessarily, as the body may not float but be used for storing the liquid, i.e. container.
The liquid exerts pressure in all directions it is in contact with the container. So, it follows logically that the stress mist be exerted on all directions the liquid is in contact with the solid but exerted by the solid on the liquid (The direction is reverse).
There's no scenario of buoyant force as, the flask doesn't float on the liquid, so it wouldn't experience buoyant force. The viscosity also doesn't exert a direct force to be considered into action. However as said by @ChetMiller

It is stress in both cases. For an ideal fluid (zero viscosity), the stress is perpendicular to the solid surface and the normal stress exerted by the solid surface is also equal to the fluid pressure

Is absolutely correct.
Hope that helps.
